# Chrome extension: Send AJAX form to Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-chrome-extension, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension for my Rails App that sends POST data with an ajax form. But, I get the response from the server:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in AppController#getpostdata.
```

So I think I need to get an authenticity token and include that in my form.
Or, should I turn it off? And how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the token using the `form_authenticity_token` helper in a Rails view, during a `GET` request..

Alternately you can disable the token, or alternately use the `:null_session` option as this is considered the best for APIs. Consult [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-protect_from_forgery) for further info.

Answer (score 1):

You can also skip the particular api method call in the controller as given below:

skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only =>[:method_name]

Comment: This is dangerous and should be avoided as much as possible, it makes your app vulnerable to Cross Site Request